# RejectedExecutionException and clojure concurrency

Tags: debugging, concurrency, clojure, jvm

In deploying some clojure code to a new server, I've been having problems with `RejectedExecutionException` and unresponsive agents. Small examples in the REPL such as

```
(pmap #(% %) (range 10))
```

seem to work fine. However, running either `pmap` or `pcalls` throw `RejectedExecutionException`s after consuming some (a varying number, but never more than a handful) of a lazy seq. Agents, in comparison, don't throw `RejectedExecutionException`. The agents can be initialized but don't execute any actions dispatched with `send` or `send-off`.

The problem with agents sound much like the symptoms described [here](http://pveentjer.wordpress.com/2008/02/06/are-you-dealing-with-the-rejectedexecutionexception/). Also, I'm not using `shutdown-agents` anywhere.

I apologize in advance for lack of reproducible example. My primary difficulty with this issue is not being able to reproduce any of this behavior on other machines. Any suggestions are welcome!

Using 64-bit HotSpot Java 1.6.0_20 and clojure 1.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using a version of Leiningen that is broken, or have multiple conflicting versions of it and/or swank. See https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/228 - one of the many discussions about this issue, and the only one I can conveniently find at the moment.

Comment: You pegged it! It seems to me like several of the 1.6.* releases have these problems. Went back to 1.5.2.