# clojure.java.shell/sh throws RejectedExecutionException when run in a new thread

Tags: clojure, leiningen

In a new fresh leiningen project, with its core.clj containing

```
(defn show-cmd
  []
  (-> (shell/sh "ls")
    :out
    println))

(defn -main
  []
  (.start (Thread. show-cmd)))
```

See https://gist.github.com/1183753 for the complete picture.

So, I get a RejectedExecutionException thrown when I do a `lein run` on the above project. The complete stack trace is in the gist.

However, the above works just fine when put in a `.clj` file and run directly with clojure, without leiningen in the workflow. Is this a bug in leiningen/clojure or is it just me?

If its a bug, please let me know how I can let the concerned know, as this would be the first time I've found a bug :)

Thanks.

**Update** Taking @skuro's suggestion, I tried my example with the master branch clone of leiningen, but I still get the same error, as illustrated here

[image: Leiningen error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem with Leiningen which unfortunately [won't be fixed soon](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/265). Fixing it would cause other stuff to break. The workaround is to force the main function to never return:

```
(defn -main
  []
  (.start (Thread. show-cmd))
  @(promise))
```

Here, since the promise is never fulfilled, main will wait forever, thus preventing Leiningen from shutting down the executors that run agents, futures, etc.

Comment: Yep, that workaround does the trick. I hope it gets fixed soon though :). Thanks.

Comment: Actually this is fixed in 1.6.1.1

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade to the latest and greatest leiningen version, possibly compiling from sources. There's a [known bug](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/228) with leiningen that prevents threads to be correctly executed. There are also [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004292/rejectedexecutionexception-and-clojure-concurrency) on the topic, a search might help.

Comment: Right, yet another time my google-fu failed me. I'll check with the master version of lein. Thanks.

Comment: I cloned the repo and tested with that, but I still see the error. See the question, updated with details.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this related to not being able to open standard input and error when run through leiningen. to work around it us i used

```
lein uberjar && java -jar projectstandalone.jar args.
```

it was w bit slower but worked

Comment: Thanks but as you said, this method is slow. A bit too slow for my tastes I'm afraid. I have reverted to leiningen 1.5.2 for the time being.